# Vaadin 6.8.4 project cannot be started with Eclipse Juno J2EE preview jetty server - no context

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jetty, vaadin

When I try to publish a Vaadin 6.8.4 project on the "J2EE Preview" server in Eclipse Juno, I get the following error message:

```
Error 404 - Not Found

No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:    
 - myproject(/myproject)
```

When I look into my workspace's folder `.metdata.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/`there is only a `publish0.dat` file in the folder `publish` but the project is in the folder `tmp0`, is that normal? If not, what can I do to resolve this?

I use a freshly installed Java EE Version of Eclipse Juno with the Vaadin 6.8.4 plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error for a simple dynamic website and cleaning and republishing the project didn't changed any thing so I installed tomcat and project started working.

It seems like a bug or problem with the deployment structure as default folder structure for jetty is different.

*I was using the latest eclipse Juno and also tried to update it to latest repo but nothing changed

Comment: Thanks! As this question was posted a while ago I'm not sure but I think switching to Tomcat resolving the problem.